# Using external VueJs components in a VueJS project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-strap

I'm trying to use VueStrap in a VueJS project, it looks like webpacker is loading it fine, I can see this in the terminal output, however, when I try use a component from vue-strap I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "input" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

I tried including the VueStrap as a component in the Vue instance but couldn't get it to work. How do I include the VueStrap into as a component correctly?

Thanks!

This is my application.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import App from '../components/app.vue'
import VueStrap from 'vue-strap'


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'))
  const app = new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
  })

  console.log('app')
})
```

This is my app.vue file

```
<template>
  <div id='app'>
    <p> {{ message }} </p>
    <bs-input :value.sync="input" label="Username" help="Only allows lowercase letters and numbers."
    error="Insert username" placeholder="Username can't start with a number." pattern="^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$"
    :mask="mask" minlength="5" readonly required icon>
  </bs-input>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        message: "Hello World"        
      }
    }
  }
</script>



<style scoped>
  p {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I've never used VueStrap before, but from the docs it seems that you should import whatever part you want to use from the component itself. So in this case `import {bs-import} from 'vue-strap'` in the app.vue file

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation on complication scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope), notably:

> Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in child scope.

Your template includes `input` and `mask` properties but your `data` function does not set those up.  They need to be set up and reactive so if they change, Vue can pass them down to the child component (which it looks like your `bs-input` component exposes an `input` and `mask` properties).